# import users gmail contacts to my website and send invitation to all their contacts

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hi i like to implement like tell a friend concept in my website.if user clicks the links it has to fetch their gmail contacts and has to send the mail to their gmail/yahoo contacts.
how can i do this? any sample site/link are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever bother to look at the related questions?

Comment: If you had use google app engine (java/python), you would have some easy functions to do the job. Either way, the user could export its own contacts as well : https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24911

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For google contacts: [Google Contacts Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html)
For yahoo contacts: [Yahoo! Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/)

Also you can simply search for [Insert company here] contacts API on any search engine and I will bet you will find plenty of examples.